# Can i run sql script through linq

Tags: .net, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a sql script file and i want to run that i can use sqlcommand for that but in my appliction im using linq. So i want to know can i run that script through linq if yes how can i do

Comment: Can you store the SQL in a proc?  You can call a proc from LINQ to SQL too, in addition to ExecuteCommand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`DataContext.ExecuteCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.executecommand.aspx) method to send your SQL directly to the database.

Answer (score 1):

If your script contains multiple statements you will need to parse it and execute them one at a time using `DataContext.ExecuteCommand`, otherwise things wont go well.
How you do this really depends on how your scripts are formatted.